# Information Security Governance - security measures

Tags: requirements

We are about to sign a contract with an OCR service provider  (Scanned documents(personal information) will be sent, which will be processed OCR, data transmitted back and documents deleted.)The service provider offers an OCR service using an application developed by him available in the cloud.
We use an internally developed interface to upload photos of IDs that are sent through an API integration of the provider's OCR application.

According to the internal policies, we asked the supplier for a series of security requirements such as:
Existence of a security policy, testing from the point of view of the security of the application, code robustness analyzes - evidence that they have been carried out.
The provider refuses to meet these requirements on the grounds that they offer access to an OCR service, not software, not licenses.

Please tell me from your experience, if you know of cases in which providers offering such services must / should not meet the required security requirements.
Thank you!

Comment: If your company thinks it is necessary, any contractor should comply with the required security measures. This is done by a contract section that must stipulate what they must respect in regard to security.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. If the supplier is a re-seller, then you need to ask the OCR service, not the re-seller ...

Comment: Please edit the question to include what the vendor is actually doing and their relationship to the service and their access to the data you send. Details are important.

Comment: Thank you @schroeder♦ for your specification! The service provider offers an OCR service using an application developed by him available in the cloud.
We use an internally developed interface to upload photos of IDs that are sent through API integration of the provider's OCR application.
  I am almost certain that we are able to ask them to meet these security requirements, however I call on your experience for confirmation.

Comment: Basically, the vendor offers us a service of OCR. (receives the scanned documents in the cloud, OCR them with the help of his application and sends us the data back, deleting sended documents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Must/should not" becomes a matter of law or regulation, which we cannot speak to. In some jurisdictions (and the number is growing) they have a responsibility to comply with requests like yours, so you could check into that.

From your description, the application was **developed** by them, **hosted** by them, and **operated** by them. They are the only ones to whom your questions *could* be asked. And your questions are not strange or unique. They are pretty basic, actually.

What it sounds like is that he is not prepared for that level of governance/auditing. Which is fair if the company is new and small. They *could* answer the questions, but they are not prepared to and are likely uneasy providing answers without understanding their liabilities in answering.